# Select element by sibling content

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

```
<p>
    <strong>
        <span>Content</span>
    </strong>
</p>

<table>

</table>
```

As shown, the `table` element is the target which I want to select, while the only thing I can make sure is that the text `Content` in its preceding sibling will not change.

So is it possible to select the `table` according to the `Content` by css or xpath?

Comment: People who down-vote this post, could you stand up and give me a reason? I do not think this question violate the sf guidelines.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but some possible motivations might be : 1. you didn't show any attempted XPath to solve the problem (selecting the target element) so far. 2. Image is not as useful as text in the sense that one needs to retype everything shown in the picture if he wants to test his XPath to make sure it works before posting an answer.

Comment: I have explained below the image, furthermore, why I use image is that I am not good at  English, so I am afraid people can not understand me. And for the attempts, I really does not know how to get started. But, thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Btw, you don't need to be fluent in English to post HTML as text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some variants of XPath to find the same `table` element, even considering only that little HTML snippet. Personally, I'll possibly use one of the following :

```
//p[normalize-space()='Content']/following-sibling::table[1]

//p[strong/span/span='Content']/following-sibling::table[1]

//span[text() = 'Content']/following::table[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer can be:
    `//table[preceding::span[text()='Content']]`

The **preceding** axis name selects all nodes that appear before the current node in the document, except ancestors, attribute nodes and namespace nodes, while the **text()** allows specifying the condition about the content.